# Regarding an input variable on .aspx page which is not running on server and code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an input variable which is manipulated using JavaScript on the client side:

```
<input type="text" id="field1"  value="Sunday, July 30th in the Year 1967 CE" />
```

How can I use the input value to write to the database on click event in my code-behind?

Comment: Are you using CGI or something for your backend? What is particularly `C` about this problem?

Comment: It's particularly easy to `C` that the question was incorrectly tagged :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
<input type="text" id="field1"  value="Sunday, July 30th in the Year 1967 CE" />
```

Change it to

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then set value in JS using something like:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').value
```

The in code behind get the value

```
txtDate.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very broad question, but in short you need to add `runat="server"` to the input so you can get the value in code-behind:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" runat="server" value="Sunday, July 30th in the Year 1967 CE" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the value and perform save logic here
    string val = field1.Value;
}
```

It's important to note that after adding `runat="server"` to the input, in JavaScript you'll need to access the control by it's ClientID:

```
var el = document.getElementById("<%= field1.ClientID %>");
if (el){
    el.value = "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to receive data from Client is to Use above `<input>` in a `<form>` tag with `method` attribute set to `POST`. Then you can receive the data from `<input>` tag in form collection in postback.